# In crm 2013 the AttributeInfo.GetValue returns wrong value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We are experiencing a strange issue, which can be reproduced by following below steps:

1. Open New Task (Or any other entity)
2. Enter text “Test Subject” in “Subject” field (or use any other field).
3. Use this Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").getValue(); statement to
   get the value of subject’s field, it will return “Test Subject”.
4. Now clear the subject field.
5. Use this Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").getValue(); statement to
   get the value of subject’s field, it will return “Test Subject”,
   which is wrong value, the subject field is empty.

The `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").getValue()` returns wrong value. We checked this issue in CRM 2011 and its ok **the issue is specific to CRM 2013**.

**EDIT:**

- This code is fired from Custom Ribbon Button.
- We tried to change the focus to another control and then we checked the value, it not works.

**EDIT:**

- This issue occurs only if the field is a `required` field.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so where yours code is called from?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. I hope you don't have value hardcoded anywhere in your javascript.

Comment: Strange!! 
I can reproduce it in the browser console....

Comment: OK, I was not aware that you are running JS in browser console. Have you tried the same JS for non-required field? May be its automatically focusing on error field. I am just guessing :)

Comment: I am using code from a ribbon button, above is the simplified version of that code.
The same code works fine for non-required field.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of CRM page is that it changes data inside of the Xrm.Page.data object only if the edited field lost focus (this event tells CRM that the data entry is done), so it could be that after step 4 you don't lose focus to other field. This behavior is the same as in CRM 2011.

Comment: and how it is possible to execute a javascript code (inside another onchange/onsave event) without losing the focus of the control? by magic? he executed the javascript code, ergo the field lost focus.

Comment: Don't see where he executed the Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").getValue() statement. I've done that in browser console and reproduced the issue. In CRM 2011 it can be reproduced via ribbon button script.

Comment: of course if you execute in browser console you get the previous value, because the field didn't lost the focus, but in a normal behavior if you execute another onchange/onsave javascript code you will always lost the focus of the current control. Because he is executing its second getValue in another position (or for the onchage of the same control) and he get the value means that the field lost focus or the javascript will not be executed at all. (and as he said this behavior only happens with CRM 2013, because the same come for him works in CRM 2011)

Comment: I have already tried by moving the focus to another control but it not works, sorry I did not mentioned it in my initial question; I have modified my question now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems here although they maybe cause by the same thing. This is unfortunately not an answer to these problems but an attempt to clarify the above.

**Problem 1**: JavaScript reads previous value when an empty value is entered.

I think this is the same as the original problem of this post.
This is also posted at: http://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mpndynamics/forum/mpndyncrm/javascript-reads-previous-value-when-an-empty/f7b8dffd-3a21-48ae-8dca-4c5467ea8272

On the Competitor form.
Enter “Oliver” in the name field.
Then read it in JavaScript as below.

```
function ClickHandler()
{
    var nameValue = "";
    nameValue = locationValue = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();   
   
    var test1 = "";
}
```

You should get “Oliver” as expected.
Then go back to the Competitor form and manually delete the text with the backspace key.
Now read what is in the name field with JavaScript as was done earlier.
You would expect to get nothing but you get “Oliver”.
Now enter Mark in the name field.
Read the field with JavaScript and you get “Mark” as you should.
So it seems when an empty value is entered following a previous value the JavaScript reads the previous value.
To put it a different way. It seems that there is a problem if the Name field had a value and the text then gets manually deleted.  The Xrm.Page object will not update to the empty string. The Xrm.Page object will however update to a non-empty value.

**Problem 2: Javascript cannot read the value in the text field if the field has not lost focus.**

This is also posted at http://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mpndynamics/forum/mpndyncrm/javascript-cannot-read-the-value-in-the-text-field/ecc2c9e0-fba0-44f2-93cd-320d042896f0?tm=1389885238744

Javascript cannot read the value in the text field if the field has not lost focus.
On the "Recurring Appointment" form I have an IFRAME that runs Javascript. It reads the value in the location field when a button is pressed. If I change the value in the location field to say "Brunswick Street" and press the button I get nothing read (i.e. in the code below locationValue is null).
However if I change the value in the location field to say "Brunswick Street".  I then then click away to somewhere on the form other than the IFRAME so the location field has lost its focus (this can also be achieved by pressing enter/tab after entering the text in the location field). If I then press the button on the IFRAME the Javascript will read the text in the location field correctly.
I gather that this is because parent.Xrm.Page is only updated when focus is lost in a field.

```
function ClickHandler()
{
    var locationValue = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("location").getValue();
}
```

I tried changing the focus in the JavaScript by setting it to requiredattendees field. But this did not work.

```
parent.Xrm.Page.getControl("requiredattendees").setFocus();
```

I used to use parent.document.forms[0].namedItem(srcDataFlds[fld]).value; to get the value in CRM 4 and 2011 but this does not work in CRM 2013. So as the SDK suggested I changed the code to use  parent.Xrm.Page however it seems to give the problem above.

The questions are why is the focus not lost when I click the button on the IFRAME? If I click on any field in the form the focus changes so why not the IFRAME.
Also how can I get the JavaScript to read the value in the location field without having to click away from the location field. (Hopefully read the value in a supported way)?
I just want the user to be able to enter the value in the location field and click the button in the IFRAME.
I also noticed that when you click the IFRAME the On Change Event is not fired for the location field.
So far the only way round this is to click on another field (or pressing enter/tab) before clicking on the button that fires the Javascript.

**Both these problems have been recognized by Microsoft and have been fixed in  “Update Rollup 1 for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Service Pack 1”**